# How to add namespace in CompilerParameters

Tags: c#

Is it possible to add namespace in a CompilerParameters object which I will ultimately use in a CompileAssemblyFromSource function of a CSharpCodeProvider object. If not then is there any way to include that namespace?

Comment: Give us some sample code to illustrate your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces from the sources you feed it to build the output assembly should all be visible.

Namespaces from other assemblies will be visible only after you've added those (other assemblies) to CompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.

You have an example in the documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.referencedassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx

'Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Suppose I have a namespace named "something" inside the "something.cs" file which is included in the project. What should I write in CompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(???)?

Comment: Well, you don't have to. Your Something namespace should be visible. My answer was for the sake of completeness, as I wasn't sure whether you were alluding to namespaces found only in your current sources, and not in other assemblies.

Comment: For some reason a function was not working so I thought the namespace was not added. But, seems like you are right, fixed that function now it works fine. Thank you for saving me a ton of hours which I would have wasted looking for how to add namespace into CompilerParameters.